# Maya Python: find middle point transform on curve

Tags: python, maya

I'm having difficulty finding a way to get a transform for the middle spot on a curve. I haven't gone as far as rebuilding the curve evenly with a ton of points, as that seems a bit overkill. `curve` and `curvePoint` don't seem to get that data.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this in one call?

Comment: what do you mean by middle spot ? on curve or in bbox ?

Comment: Hey @john, have you tried my answer?

Comment: @ababak yes cheers, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pointOnCurve](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/index.html?contextId=COMMANDSPYTHON-POINTONCURVE&form=MY01SV&OCID=MY01SV) command to query point attributes (positions, normals, tangents, curvature and so on):

```py
from maya import cmds

# Define number of control points for our circle
num_sections = 6
# Define substeps to query between control points
num_substeps = 4
# Create a circle
curve_transform, curve_make = cmds.circle(sections=num_sections)
for n in range(num_sections + 1):
    for i in range(num_substeps):
        k = n + 1.0 / num_substeps * i
        if k > num_sections:
            break
        print("position({:.2f}) = {}".format(k, cmds.pointOnCurve(curve_transform, position=True, parameter=k)))
```

Result:

```
position(0.00) = [5.551115123125783e-17, 1.0, 0.0]
position(0.25) = [-0.25710129174850527, 0.9640625000000002, 0.0]
position(0.50) = [-0.4979646071760523, 0.8625, 0.0]
position(0.75) = [-0.7063519699616827, 0.7046875000000001, 0.0]
position(1.00) = [-0.8660254037844386, 0.5000000000000001, 0.0]
position(1.25) = [-0.9634532617101879, 0.25937500000000024, 0.0]
position(1.50) = [-0.9959292143521046, 2.498001805406602e-16, 0.0]
position(1.75) = [-0.9634532617101882, -0.25937499999999963, 0.0]
position(2.00) = [-0.8660254037844389, -0.49999999999999967, 0.0]
position(2.25) = [-0.706351969961683, -0.7046874999999997, 0.0]
position(2.50) = [-0.4979646071760526, -0.8624999999999998, 0.0]
position(2.75) = [-0.25710129174850566, -0.9640624999999998, 0.0]
position(3.00) = [-4.718447854656915e-16, -1.0, 0.0]
position(3.25) = [0.2571012917485048, -0.9640625000000002, 0.0]
position(3.50) = [0.49796460717605184, -0.8625000000000003, 0.0]
position(3.75) = [0.7063519699616824, -0.7046875000000004, 0.0]
position(4.00) = [0.8660254037844386, -0.5000000000000007, 0.0]
position(4.25) = [0.963453261710188, -0.25937500000000063, 0.0]
position(4.50) = [0.9959292143521046, -7.355227538141662e-16, 0.0]
position(4.75) = [0.9634532617101882, 0.25937499999999925, 0.0]
position(5.00) = [0.866025403784439, 0.4999999999999992, 0.0]
position(5.25) = [0.7063519699616831, 0.7046874999999995, 0.0]
position(5.50) = [0.4979646071760525, 0.8624999999999998, 0.0]
position(5.75) = [0.2571012917485054, 0.9640624999999998, 0.0]
position(6.00) = [5.551115123125783e-17, 1.0, 0.0]
```

The `parameter` argument is from 0 to the number of control points on the curve. You may also query using a normalized parameter from 0 to 1:

```py
for k in range(10 + 1):
    print("position({:.2f}) = {}".format(k / 10.0, cmds.pointOnCurve(curve_transform, position=True, parameter=k / 10.0, turnOnPercentage=True)))
```

Result:

```
position(0.00) = [5.551115123125783e-17, 1.0, 0.0]
position(0.10) = [-0.5861259932813082, 0.8056000000000001, 0.0]
position(0.20) = [-0.9491638425477449, 0.3096, 0.0]
position(0.30) = [-0.9491638425477451, -0.3095999999999995, 0.0]
position(0.40) = [-0.5861259932813081, -0.8056000000000001, 0.0]
position(0.50) = [-4.718447854656915e-16, -1.0, 0.0]
position(0.60) = [0.5861259932813074, -0.8056000000000005, 0.0]
position(0.70) = [0.9491638425477444, -0.30960000000000143, 0.0]
position(0.80) = [0.9491638425477449, 0.3096, 0.0]
position(0.90) = [0.5861259932813081, 0.8055999999999998, 0.0]
position(1.00) = [5.551115123125783e-17, 1.0, 0.0]
```